# Jquery Disable Click on a div with attribute

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have a page where I have to disable a div click through an attribute. What wrong am I doing here?

```
HTML Code
    <div title="You cannot edit when value is in Closed status" clickdisabled="disable">
                        <a href="/122/edit">edit</a>
                    </div>



Jquery Code
    $([clickdisabled = "disable"]).attr("disabled", "disabled").off('click');
```

Comment: I don't understand the you need. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$( "div[clickdisabled='disable'] a" ).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just be able to do this as well.

```
  $( "div[clickdisabled='disable'] a" ).off("click");
```